# HTML/JQUERY - resize iframe doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm using jquery to resize iframe based on content
Locally everything works well, but when the application is deployed, frequently the iframe is not resized

Maybe it's a "synchronisation" problem: resizeIframe is fired before the content is completely loaded. (Note that the content is big)

```
<div id="content">
    <iframe id="display"  name="tht" width="100%" src="path" onload='javascript:resizeIframe();'></iframe>
</div>



function resizeIframe() {    
          $('#display').height($('#display').contents().height());
}
```

Is there something to do to ensure that the resizeIframe function resizes the iframe correctly?

Comment: Try to clear your browser's cache.

Comment: I don't think its comes from browser's cache. It's appear frequently even if I refresh the page.

Comment: Are you able to change the content of page which you load in iframe?

Comment: Have you tried to run the function on `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: Yes I choose and change dynamically the content of the iframe

Comment: @Slim: yes I tried also but its worse: the iframe is not resizd at all

Comment: @Jils How many lines are you returnining in teh iframe? The browsers are facing issues if there is no paging. Sorry for asking so many questions, but I'm trying to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Slim: I tried to display a log file in the iframe, the file can contain more than 2000 lines

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function resize(width, height)
{
var display = document.getElementById('display');
display.style.width = width + 'px';
display.style.height = height + 'px';
}
</script>

<iframe id="display" name="tht" src="src" onload="resize(10, 10)" />
```

Comment: I don't understand why the height is set to 10px?

Comment: you can set whatever height you want to set, it takes in any number parameter without the 'px'..it could be more..try it.

Comment: But I cannot know in advance the height of the content

Comment: what exactly are you looking for then? what do you mean by knowing in advance?

Comment: The height that I have to put in 'resize' comes from the file indicated in the src's frame. So I have to wait for the loading content before putting the height.

Comment: if possible, please upload the src